# Regular Expression in Notepad++ to replace < and > inside CDATA

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ to fix a huge XML export file and one of the challenges here is to replace all `<` and `>` characters to `&lt;` and `&gt;`. The thing is, I can't simply use the replace all action since the XML file is full of < and > that cannot be changed.

Luckly all the `<` and `>` that I need to change are wrapped by CDATA tags, like this:

```
<![CDATA[Text here... <span class="vSpecial"><p>Special Offer - more text here!</p></span>]]>
```

I was wondering if there'd be a **Regular Expression** to identify `<` and `>` wrapped in CDATA content, so I could easily use the Replace All to change only them.

**UPDATE**

The content of CDATA can contain line breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/KWx8uR/1)

```
<!\[CDATA\[)(?:(?!\]\]>).)*?\K(?:(<)|(>))
```

Replacement: `(?{1}&lt;)(?{2}&gt;)`

**Note**: For display purposes the link above uses `\G(?!\A)`. This is not supported in Notepad++, thus it's been dropped in the actual answer. I added it to the link to show what it basically does.

See the [Notepadd++ documentation](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions#Search_modifiers) for more information. It mentions the following:

> For those readers familiar with Perl, `\G` is not supported.

---

### Results

#### Before

[image: Before]

#### After

[image: After]

---

### Explanation

Click `Replace All` repeatedly until the message at the bottom shows `Replace All: 0 occurrences were replaced.` It will replace the first occurrence, then the second occurrence, then third, etc. for each `CDATA` that is found until there are no more matches.

#### Pattern

- `<!\[CDATA\[` Matches `<![[CDATA[` literally
- `(?:(?!\]\]>).)*?` Tempered lazy token matching any character any number of times, but as few as possible ensuring what follows doesn't match `]]>`
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
- `(?:(<)|(>))` Match either of the following

  - `(<)` Capture `<` literally into capture group 1
  - `(>)` Capture `>` literally into capture group 2

#### Replacement

Notepad++ allows conditional replacements, so `(?{1}&lt;)` makes reference to capture group one and `(?{2}&gt;)` makes reference to capture group 2.

Comment: it worked perfectly! **Thanks a lot!** Just a question, the Replace All for this matter is not replacing them all in one shot. Each click on this option replaces only one instead of the whole document. Is this something related to this regular expression or am I missing something?

Comment: @AdrianoCastro I updated the answer. Notepad++ doesn't support `\G`, unfortunately, so your only option is to click `Replace All` repeatedly until you get the message I specify in my answer. If `\G` was supported you could use the regex in the regex101 link (top of the **Code** section in my answer) and click once to replace every occurrence.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, I think you accidentally changed the regex when you updated your answer. It was `(?:<!\[CDATA\[|\G(?!\A))(?:(?!\]\]>).)*?\K(?:(<)|(>))` and now it's `<!\[CDATA\[)(?:(?!\]\]>).)*?\K(?:(<)|(>))`

Comment: @AdrianoCastro I put a note in the **Code** section. I realized `\G` isn't supported by Notepad++, so I removed it, which is also why you couldn't simply do a single "replace all".

Comment: [Both \G and \K aren't available on some earlier versions of Notepad++. I don't remember exactly when they were introduced, but they work on v6.5.2.](https://superuser.com/questions/741659/how-to-remove-characters-from-a-matching-string)

Comment: @sln interesting. If you want you can create a program to go through [all the changelogs](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/) to find information relating to those two tags? Lol

Comment: No thanks. I was just looking over the post here, and I thought I'd seen a few times in the past where answers (accepted ones) used `\G`. Just did a google one it. I don't use np++ so just trying to help a bit.

Comment: @sln I've seen it used too, but when I referred to the docs it showed as not working (I also tested it with the newest release and it wasn't working)

Comment: Nice to know for future reference.